# Volume change in Fedora only applies when the volume icon is gone?

Tags: fedora, audio, audio-volume

So I have this unexpected behavior when changing volume under newest Fedora 32 (Gnome 3 default version):

When I change volume, it doesn't change right away on every Fn+F2/F3 keypress - the volume actually changes once the volume change icon disappears from the screen. So if I pressed the combo a few times, the sound will still be as it was, and then it will suddenly change when the icon disappears. It's not super inconvenient, it just feels weird after using Ubuntu where the volume changes on every press immediately, even when the icon is still on screen. Any idea if this is normal or if it could be changed somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out it's a pulseaudio configuration issue. For some reason it had the **enable-deferred-volume** attribute set to "yes". Just edit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf, uncomment that param, set it to **no** and restart pulseaudio (or system).